# Kernel breaks on adding new code (that never runs)

Tags: c, assembly, linux-kernel, arm

I'm trying to add some logic at boundaries between userspace and kernelspace particularly on the ARM architecture.

One such boundary appears to be the `vector_swi` routine implemented in `arch/arm/kernel/entry-common.S`. Right now, I have most of my code written in a C function which I would like to call somewhere at the start of `vector_swi`.

Thus, I did the following:

```
ENTRY(vector_swi)
        sub     sp, sp, #S_FRAME_SIZE
        stmia   sp, {r0 - r12}                  @ Calling r0 - r12
 ARM(   add     r8, sp, #S_PC           )
 ARM(   stmdb   r8, {sp, lr}^           )       @ Calling sp, lr
 THUMB( mov     r8, sp                  ) 
 THUMB( store_user_sp_lr r8, r10, S_SP  )       @ calling sp, lr
        mrs     r8, spsr                        @ called from non-FIQ mode, so ok.
        str     lr, [sp, #S_PC]                 @ Save calling PC
        str     r8, [sp, #S_PSR]                @ Save CPSR
        str     r0, [sp, #S_OLD_R0]             @ Save OLD_R0
        zero_fp

#ifdef CONFIG_BTM_BOUNDARIES
        bl btm_entering_kernelspace    @ <--- My function
#endif
```

When the contents of my function are as follows everything works fine:

```
static int btm_enabled = 0;
asmlinkage inline void btm_entering_kernelspace(void)
{
        int cpu;
        int freq;
        struct acpu_level *level;
        if(!btm_enabled) {
                return;
        }
        cpu = smp_processor_id();
        freq = acpuclk_krait_get_rate(cpu);
        (void) cpu;
        (void) freq;
        (void) level;
}
```

However, when I add some additional code, the kernel enters into a crash-reboot loop.

```
static int btm_enabled = 0;
asmlinkage inline void btm_entering_kernelspace(void)
{
        int cpu;
        int freq;
        struct acpu_level *level;
        if(!btm_enabled) {
                return;
        }
        cpu = smp_processor_id();
        freq = acpuclk_krait_get_rate(cpu);
        (void) cpu;
        (void) freq;
        (void) level;
        // --------- Added code ----------
        for (level = drv.acpu_freq_tbl; level->speed.khz != 0; level++) {
                if(level->speed.khz == freq) {
                        break;
                }
        }
}
```

Although the first instinct is to blame the logic of the added code, please note that none of it should ever execute since `btm_enabled` is `0`.

I have double-checked and triple-checked to make sure `btm_enabled` is `0` by adding a `sysfs` entry to print out the value of the variable (with the added code removed).

Could someone explain what is going on here or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The new code presumably changes register allocation for the earlier code, and / or maybe the compiler decides to optimistically do some things with registers before checking / returning.  Or simply save/restore some registers to the stack because the function now needs to save some args across calls.  If clobbing r0..r3 and memory below the stack pointer wasn't really safe at that point in `vector_swi`, then the first version with the function call only worked by chance.  I'm not familiar enough with Linux's ARM entry point to say whether or not an ABI-compiliant function call is safe there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first version will probably compile to just a return instruction as it has no side effect. The second needs to load `btm_enabled` and in the process overwrites one or two system call arguments.

When calling a C function from assembly language you need to ensure that registers that may be modified do not contain needed information.

To solve your specific problem, you could update your code to read:

```
#ifdef CONFIG_BTM_BOUNDARIES
        stmdb   sp!, {r0-r3, r12, lr}  @ <--- New instruction
        bl btm_entering_kernelspace    @ <--- My function
        ldmia   sp!, {r0-r3, r12, lr}  @ <--- New instruction
#endif
```

The new instructions store registers r0-r3, r12 and lr onto the stack and restore them after your function call. These are the only registers a C function is allowed to modify, saving r12 here is unnecessary here is it's value is not used, but doing so keeps the stack 8-byte aligned as required by the ABI.

Comment: Ah yes, so my guess was right that call clobbered registers were still holding something important at that point?  The entry point already saved them to the stack, but it uses them without reloading, right?

Comment: Yes, used without reloading for most system calls.

Comment: Don't C functions automatically have assembly generated that saves and restores registers? I took a look at 10-15 functions from `objdump` and they all start off with `mov ip, sp; push {r3, r4, ...}` and end with `ldm sp, {r3, r4, ....}`

Comment: I'm guessing what I should be doing is save the registers onto the stack, call my function and then load them back. Since I don't have a good understanding of assembly, Is there any way I can get the compiler to generate this assembly for me so that I can look it up and hand-write it into `vector_swi`?

Comment: Just use `objdump -S` on the generated vmlinux or whatever your output is.

Comment: @GuruPrasad: The kernel already saved all the registers to the stack on entry with `stmia   sp, {r0 - r12}`.  You don't need to store them again, just use 4 `ldr` instructions to reload those registers after your function returns, using the right offset from `sp`.  Or if you can use `ldm` without an auto-increment/decrement addressing mode, that would work too.  (ldm and stm aren't magic; multiple separate `ldr` instructions aren't much slower, I think, just take more code size.)